# LINQ OrderBy Clause - Force certain string to always be at the top

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following LINQ OrderBy clause:

```
Menu[] sorted = ret.OrderBy(menu => menu.Title).ToArray();
```

This works great, as menus are sorted in the order of their title.

However, if the title happens to be "Favorites", I want it to always be the first element in the array no matter what.

What's the easiest way to do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd say:

```
Menu[] sorted = ret.OrderBy(menu => menu.Title != "Favorites")
                   .ThenBy(menu => menu.Title)
                   .ToArray();
```

Comment: I think you should use OrderByDescending in the first statement

Comment: Yea, or just do a `!=` instead of `==` - Either way, this works great!

Comment: No, it's interpreting `true` as `1`: an `OrderBy` goes from lowest to highest, so from `0` to `1`, so from `false` to `true`.